# SSL certificate expired when creating cUrl request. domain -> subdomain.domain (Magento)

Tags: ssl, magento, ssl-certificate

- In magento project, I am creating cUrl request from domain.com to subdomain.domain.com
- It worked fine until today when at some point it started to always throws an error: **SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired.**

Both certificates are valid and not yet expired.

This is part of the code for creating cUrl request:

```
        // OK cool - then let's create a new cURL resource handle
    $ch = curl_init();

    // Determine whether this is a GET or POST
    if ($post_body !== null) {
        $httpMethod = $httpMethod ?? 'POST';
        // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        // Alows to keep the POST method even after redirect
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $httpMethod);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_body);

        // Default content type is form encoded
        $content_type = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';

        // Determine if this is a JSON payload and add the appropriate content type
        if (is_object(json_decode($post_body))) {
            $content_type = 'application/json';
        }

        // Add POST-specific headers
        $headers[] = "Content-Type: {$content_type}";
        $headers[] = 'Content-Length: ' . strlen($post_body);

    }

    // If we set some headers include them
    if(count($headers) > 0) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    }

    // Set URL to download
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    if (isset($this->httpProxy)) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $this->httpProxy);
    }

    // Include header in result? (0 = yes, 1 = no)
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

    // Allows to follow redirect
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

    /**
     * Set cert
     * Otherwise ignore SSL peer verification
     */
    if (isset($this->certPath)) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, $this->certPath);
    }

    if($this->verifyHost) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    } else {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    }

    if($this->verifyPeer) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
    } else {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    }

    // Should cURL return or print out the data? (true = return, false = print)
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    // Timeout in seconds
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $this->timeOut);

    // Download the given URL, and return output
    $output = curl_exec($ch);

    // HTTP Response code from server may be required from subclass
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    $this->responseCode = $info['http_code'];

    if ($output === false) {
        throw new OpenIDConnectClientException('Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch));
    }

    // Close the cURL resource, and free system resources
    curl_close($ch);

    return $output;
```

In this condition it always fails:

```
if ($output === false) {
    throw new OpenIDConnectClientException('Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch));
}
```

**Important note:** Code is untouched for years and always worked fine

Maybe I need to configure something on magento server but I have no idea what?

Comment: https://letsencrypt.org/docs/dst-root-ca-x3-expiration-september-2021/

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar t hanks for answer! So how it can be fixed?